# Is my email header correct?

Tags: php, mime

Is the following "From" header incorect?

```
    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: Mail Master <mail@mailmaster.com>' . "\r\n";
if(sendEmailNow($email, $subject, $body, $headers)){
```

I get the error from my mail server. It says "Mail from error: Syntax error".

Thanks all for any help.

### Update

I have stripped down the SendEmailNow function to the below and I get the same error:

```
//send an email
function sendEmailNow($email, $subject, $body, $headers){

    if (mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
      ##check email
      ##code to say email sent - compare with the number registered
      return true;
     }

     else {
      ##code to report an error 
      return false;
     }

 }
```

### Update 2

Problem solved. I am running this on a windows machine using PHP 5. Like the correct answer chosen and the comments have said. Some mail servers have trouble understanding what I had previously. But what worked for me was this:

```
$headers .= 'From: mail@mailmaster.com' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Google search for the error message suggests that some SMTP servers fail to parse your syntax for the `From` header. Can you try the following syntax to rule out this possibility?

```
From: mail@mailmaster.com
```

Comment: This is likely to be the culprit, especially if PHP is running under Windows; a shocking number of SMTP servers can't cope with the (perfectly valid) `First Last <email>` syntax.

Comment: I've seen that syntax in the form "First Last" <email>. Try sticking double quotes around the name.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the body is empty, you may need an additional CRLF to terminate the headers.  Without knowing the API I can't say much more.

Comment: I tried the extra CRLF, I still get the same syntax error. What do you mean by API?

Comment: Probably the sendEmailNow function. What's the code for that?

Comment: Ah I see. Its exactly the same as the mail() function - it just checks if the email is in the right format first nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this'll help, but here's what the output headers look like in my Python app in pure-text:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="10.254.26.130.1.1364.1241389770.060.1"
From: User1 <user1@domain1.com>
To: User2 <user2@domain1.com>,User3 <user3@domain.com>
Subject: Actual subject
MIME-Version: 1.0


--10.254.26.130.1.1364.1241389770.060.1
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

actual text content starting here...
```

Again, without knowing all the content/headers it's hard to say, but I'd guess either a) You've left out the trailing CRLFs before the content, or b) one of the earlier headers missing its CRLF.

Apologies if that takes you in a wildly wrong direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
From: "User1" <user1@domain1.com>
```

The From header requires quotes for the name part.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the "$userEmail" variable in your form, you can have it from them and a reply to. The $email_id is your email it is sent to.

```
        $to=$email_id;
        $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($userEmail) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($userEmail) . "\r\n";
```